# Patroni's unable to create the PostgreSQL data directory (/mnt/data/patroni) during initialization

Tags: patroni

This is my patroni.yml file
[root@Postgres-1 etc]# cat patroni.yml
scope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: postgres-1

## this name must be unique for each node to diferentiate them

## Ex: postgresql1  for node 1, postgresql2 for node 2 and so on.

restapi:
listen: 10.5.0.4:8008
connect_address: 10.5.0.4:8008

etcd3:
host: 10.5.0.7:2379

bootstrap:
dcs:
ttl: 30
loop_wait: 10
retry_timeout: 10
maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
postgresql:
use_pg_rewind: true
initdb:
- encoding: UTF8
- data-checksums

```
pg_hba:
#access rules to allow access to postgesql from network
- host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
- host replication replicator 10.5.0.4/0 md5
- host replication replicator 10.5.0.6/0 md5
- host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

users:
    admin:
        password: admin
        # Password must meet internal password policies of your company
        options:
            - createrole
            - createdb
```

postgresql:
listen: 10.5.0.4:5432
connect_address: 10.5.0.4:5432
data_dir: /mnt/data/patroni
#in this folder the database files will be stored
pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
authentication:
replication:
username: replicator
password: password
# This is the user used internally by PostgreSQL for cluster replication
# Password must meet internal password policies of your company
superuser:
username: postgres
password: password
# This initializes the password for the postgres admin user
# Password must meet internal password policies of your company

```
parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: '.'
```

tags:
nofailover: false
noloadbalance: false
clonefrom: false
nosync: false

I have already created
mkdir -p /mnt/data/patroni
chown postgres:postgres /mnt/data/patroni
chmod 700 /mnt/data/patroni

No files or directory getting created inside /mnt/data/patroni and keep on showing this log on both postgres nodes

Mar 25 02:18:46 Postgres-1 systemd[1]: Started Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL.
Mar 25 02:18:46 Postgres-1 patroni[11614]: 2024-03-25 02:18:46,884 INFO: No PostgreSQL configuration items changed, nothing to reload.
Mar 25 02:18:46 Postgres-1 patroni[11614]: 2024-03-25 02:18:46,890 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am postgres-1
Mar 25 02:18:46 Postgres-1 patroni[11614]: 2024-03-25 02:18:46,933 INFO: waiting for leader to bootstrap

[root@Postgres-1 etc]# /usr/local/bin/patronictl -c /etc/patroni.yml list

- Cluster: postgres (7349515419481038011) --+----+-----------+
  | Member     | Host     | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
  +------------+----------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
  | postgres-1 | 10.5.0.4 | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |
  | postgres-2 | 10.5.0.6 | Replica | stopped |    |   unknown |

Team, please guide me

Note: I tried changing data_dir path but still same issue.